# Connecting Python with MySQL - Getting Started

Tags: python, mysql, download

I have MySQL and Python on my computer. I want to write statements in Python scripts that extract (SELECT) data from a MySQL schema and other statements that INSERT data into MySQL tables.

My version of Python is 2.7, and I installed it via Anaconda.

From what I have read it would be appropriate to use the module “import MySQLdb”. But before doing so, I would need to download and install some code that supports this module. The only code that I have found that might work are mysql-connector-python-2.1.5-py2.7-winx64.msi or mysql-connector-python-2.1.5-py2.7-win32.msi.

When I execute either of those MSI’s, the result is a pop-up with an error message: “Python 2.7 not found. We only support Python installed using the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) downloaded from http://www.python.org/download/. Please check the Connector/Python manual on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ for more information."

I skimmed the Connector/Python manual to find more information about the incompatibility; no luck. I checked the PATH on my computer; it does include c:\users\sncole\Anaconda, and python.exe does reside in this folder. 
Is there any way that I can use one of the MSI’s mentioned above, or is there another download that I can use for Python that was installed via Anaconda?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have installed Anaconda correctly, `conda` should be in your path. Then you can install mysql connector by typing

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: This worked for me.  conda.exe did reside in a folder in PATH.  Instead of importing MySQLdb, I used 'import mysql.connector'.